# Resetting background color after jquery .click() event

Tags: jquery, css, click

I have a list of tracks, and when you click on a track, a player expands and the track gets selected in the hover background color. This works fine, but when another track is clicked, it doesn't remove the hover background color from the old track. Here is the code I'm using, and here is a test link: http://shacktown.com

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".track").click(function(){
            if ( $(this).find('.trackPlayer').is(':hidden') ) {
                $('.trackPlayer').slideUp();
                $('.trackPlayer').css('background-color', '#331100');
                $(this).css('background-color', '#997766');
                $(this).find('.trackPlayer').slideDown();
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Try with $(this).siblings().css('background-color',#default-color-hex);?

Comment: `.trackPlayer != .track`

Comment: Sure would be a lot easier for you to figure this out if you had used any jQuery variable caching at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".track").click(function(){
        if ( $(this).find('.trackPlayer').is(':hidden') ) {
            //removing color from prev. track
            $(".selectedTrack").css('background-color', '#defaultcolorgoeshere').removeClass("selectedTrack");
            $('.trackPlayer').slideUp();
            $('.trackPlayer').css('background-color', '#331100');
            $(this).css('background-color', '#997766');
            $(this).addClass("selectedTrack");
            $(this).find('.trackPlayer').slideDown();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could simplify your code quite a bit. First of all, using classes to apply styles makes the code more maintainable and readable. You can also use chaining when working with jQuery methods. It increases performance. This is how I would do it:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".track").click(function () {
        if ($(this).find('.trackPlayer').is(':hidden')) {
            // remove styles and hide the trackPlayer from the activeTrack
            $('.activeTrack').removeClass('activeTrack').find('.trackPlayer').slideUp();

            // apply styles and show the trackPlayer to the clicked track
            $(this).addClass('activeTrack').find('.trackPlayer').slideDown();
        }
    });
});
```

And the CSS:

```
.trackPlayer {
    display:none;
    background-color: #331100;
}
.activeTrack {
    background-color: #997766;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tah11u11/1/